# How to implement a 802.1x authentication in wifi accesss point?

Tags: networking, wireless

I have created a wifi access point in my ubuntu 14.04 using [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/) procedures. But instead of normal WPA2 password , I want to implement the 802.1x authentication so that any user have to have a login and password to use my wifi. And also I can monitor each users activity that way. How can I do that ?

Comment: Setting up 802.1x isn't very easy and isn't supported from the graphical user interface as far as I know. You'll need a FreeRadius server and a hostapd service running yourself. Networkmanager setup like you show in your question is just a point-and-click configuration offering very limited features. That means an answer to your question will be much more complex compared to your current set up and requires your wireless networking adapter to be unmanaged by Network manager (not configurable anymore from GUI). Are you comfortable with such an answer?

Comment: I am totally comfortable with such answer.  I knew things would complex but I wasn't able to figure where should I start.

Comment: Well, the comment above contains all you need to do:  `apt-get install freeradius` and `apt-get install hostapd`  then `man freeradius` and `man hostapd`  **;-)**